# CATransform3D - understanding the transform values

Tags: ios, core-animation

The picture shows a simple UIView after applying the following transform:

```
- (CATransform3D) transformForOpenedMenu
{
  CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
  transform.m34 = -1.0 /450;
  transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, D2R(40), 0, 1, 0);
  transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 210, 150, -500);
  return transform;
}
```

I'm trying to make the distances highlighted with black to have equal length. Could you please help me understand the logic behind the values and calculations?

Cheers

### UPD Sept 13

Looks like removing 3DTranslate keeps distances equal. I see I can use layer's frame property to reposition rotated view to the bottom left of the screen. Not yet sure, but this might actually work.

[image]

Comment: It has to do with the view not being in the center of its super view and that is why you get that kind of perspective.

Comment: Is the question about understanding the transform values or about adjusting the perspective?

Comment: More about understanding transform values, based on which perspective could be adjusted. Both would probably be the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so what eventually solved my question is this:

- 3D transform on Y axis to swing the view like a door `transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, D2R(40), 0, 1, 0);`
- set Z anchor point on a layer, to move it back `targetView.layer.anchorPointZ = 850;`
- adjust layer position so that the view is located slightly to the bottom left of the parent view:

  `newPosition.x += 135 * positionDirection;
   newPosition.y += 70 * positionDirection;`

This sequence adjusts position without `CATransform3DTranslate` and keeps the 'swinged' effect not distorted.

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2):

The .m34 value you are setting is best set on the sublayerTransform of the containing view rather than the view you are transforming.

I don't fully understand the maths behind affine transforms so I made [this project](https://github.com/jrturton/3DTransformFun) which allows me to play around with the transform values to achieve the effect I want. You can plug in the values from your code above and see what it looks like, though note that there is already a perspective value applied using the sublayerTransform property mentioned above.

For your specific case, I think you want to adjust the anchor point of the layer to (0.0,0.5) and apply the rotation transform only. This assumes you want the menu to swing back like a door, with the hinges on the left edge.

Comment: Yep, removing translate keeps highlighted distances equal. I also need to scale view down a bit and move it to the bottom left corner of the parent view; I've intended to do that via translate. Could you please recommend other way to do that?

Comment: The best thing I can recommend is that you download that project I linked to, run it in the simulator and experiment with the transforms until you get the effect you want.

Comment: That's was what I did right after reading your answer. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're seeing is caused by your CATransform3DTranslate call. You're essentially setting the Y Axis off center, and hence seeing a different perspective view of the frame.

Think of it this way;

You're standing in the center of a long narrow field stretching off into the horizon. The edge of the field appears as if it is converges to a center point somewhere off in the distance. The angle of each edge to the converging point will appear equal if you are at the center of the field. If, on the other hand, you move either to the left or the right, the angles change and one will seem greater than the other (inversely opposite of course).

This is essentially what is happening with your view; As your converging points are to the right, changing the Y axis away from 0 will have the same effect as moving to the left or right in my example above. You're no longer looking at the parallel lines from the center.

so in your code above Setting the ty in CATransform3DTranslate to 0 Should fix your problem I.E.

```
   transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 210, 0, -500);
```

You may also need to alter the tz and tx Value to make it fit.

Comment: Yep, removing translate does the trick actually. Could you please recumbent a way to move the view to the bottom-left of the screen with having highlighted distances equal?

Comment: There's not much to go on here ... by that i mean it's difficult knowing what you're trying to accomplish. Is this some animation effect... Personally, when i do this kind of stuff i use a plain view and do all my manipulation on non-view CALayers. This allows more freedom to manipulate the layers independently.