# Create perspective affine transform matrix based on point coordinates in iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Assuming I have a view (or image) like this:

[image: source image]

And I'd like to transform it to look like this:

[image: resulting image]

How do I create a CATransform3D matrix for that based on the 4 corners coordinates of the shape I'd like image to be transformed to?

[image: transform template]

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do that with a CGAffineTransform.**

A CGAffineTransform is an euclidean transformation, meaning all parallel lines will remain parallel in all cases. You only can stretch, rotate, scale and translate the object.

It will be possible with a 3D affine transform. But there is no function to get the transform based on the projection (that's what you are asking for). You'll need to do the math yourself. I can't help you with that, but someone used to 3d gaming will do it it a breeze.

I would go down the path of using a 3rd party framework that makes the transformation for you. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Ciechan/BCMeshTransformView)

Comment: Right, looks like it should be CATransform3D matrix; adjusted, thanks. Yes - I'm looking for help with the math for getting transformation based on the projection.

Comment: I see the framework you've recommended uses opengl - i'd prefer a UIKit based solution as I know nothing about opengl. Otherwise I'd appreciate if you could suggest how exactly to use that framework to achieve the result I'm looking for.

Comment: I was working on somehow similar thing 2 years ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622909/catransform3d-understanding-the-transform-values and achieved some results, but the big difference here is that I'd like to get transform based on final position vertices coordinates.